# Bounds on the number of zeros of real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $F(A)$ be a class of real-analytic function on an interval $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ minus the zero function.

We have the following theorem for $F(A)$.

> If  $f \in F(A)$ then $f$ has at most finitely many zeros $A$.

**Proof** Suppose $f\in F(A)$ has infinitely many zeros on a bounded interval. Then by Bolzano-Weierstrass the set of zeros has a  convergent subsequence in $A$. Therefore, by identity theorem, $f$ must be zero on all of $A$.
However, this contradicts our assumption that $f$ is non-zero. Q.E.D.

**My question:**   Are there ways of sharpening the bound on the number of zeros?

Let $N(f)$ be the number of zeros of $f$. Clear, there is no uniform bound on $N(f)$ for all $f\in F$. 
However, there a subset of $F$ for which we do have good upper bounds like a set of polynomials of degree $n$ in which case $N\le n$.

**My second question (or refined first question) is:** For a give $f$ which is analytic on $A$, but not a polynomial, are there ways of finding an upper bound on the number zeros of $f$?

Comment: what about sine?

Comment: Is $\sin x$ a real analytic function on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, you are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: @user64494 Try to look Bernstein Theorem

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: Don't you understand my question was rhetorical?

Comment: sin is a real analytic function since it's a class inftty and does have a fixed point in the neighberhood of x=0 , and for this question it must assume a restriction and set an interval

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, I had a mistake initially. I corrected the question.

Comment: The basic technical tool for counting and locating zeros of analytic functions is the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). The study of the distribution of zeros of classes of entire functions is a fairly classical topic (cf. [MR0087740](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=87740) and related references).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Many thanks for this.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine But the OP asks about **real** analytic functions.

Comment: @IgorRivin: True. But every real analytic function is also complex analytic, and sometimes even entire. :-) Given the breadth of the question, I figured that pointing to some well developed literature on a closely related topic might still be useful. Of course, it's up to the OP to decide for themselves.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Are you saying that the OP has multiple personalities? But seriously, since it is not at all clear what criterion the OP would like to use, I suppose you have a point.

Comment: I think it might be better to posed a more exact conjecture of your question first.

Comment: @Huxiyu What is not exact about it?

Comment: @ At least, we do not what kind of $F(A)$ you prefer, for different one with more refine structure the argument is different,.

Comment: @Huxiyu Ok. Thanks.  I would prefer $F(A)$ to be a class of real analytic function on an interval $A=[-a,a]$ for some  fixed $a>0$.  Is this enough? Should I add more? I would like to improve the question.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine   Thank you again for your reference. Are you aware of any result of similar nature for real-analytic functions?

Answer (score 7):

As noted by the comments, you must require that your interval $A$ is compact (otherwise, $\sin(1/x)$ has infinitely many zeroes on $\mathopen]0;1\mathclose[$.

Moreover, you cannot have a bound valid for every class $F(A)$, even if it only consists of polynomials — there are nonzero polynomials with as many zeroes as you wish on your interval $A$.
However, such polynomials will have unbounded degree.

This is a typical theme in o-minimality: if you bound the complexity of your class of functions, then there is a bound on the number of zeroes. 
In some cases, this bound can be effective. For exemple, if $F(A)$ consists
of exponential polynomials with at most $m$ terms of the form $x^\alpha e^{\beta x}$, then the number of zeroes is bounded from above by something like $m-1$ (without guarantee...). You can find such results in Khovanskii's book *Fewnomials*.

Answer (score 1):

As Igor Khavkine commented, the basic tool is the Argument Principle.

Given your $f$ in question 2, you want to find a neighbourhood $U$ of $A$ in $\mathbb C$ in which $f$ is analytic, and then take a closed contour $\Gamma$ in $U$ enclosing $A$.  How you find such a $U$ will depend on how you know $f$ is real-analytic on $A$.  If you can numerically approximate $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\; dz$ with an error $< 1/2$, rounding that approximation gives you the number of zeros inside $\Gamma$, and thus an upper bound on the number of zeros on $A$.